# Custom Text Fade In Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating this custom text fade in component for a project of mine and ran into an issue.

I create a list of the words by splitting the string and then map each word into it's own Typography (mui v4) component with the index of the word as the animation delay offset.

I noticed that in mobile the text doesn't seem to wrap even when the total sentence is too long and was having trouble solving this.

I tried having `word + ' '` instead of `word + '\u00a0'` and then adding `style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}` to each word but that didn't put any spaces in mobile for some reason (although it did for non-mobile).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    textFadeIn: {
        opacity: 0,
        animationName: '$fadeIn',
        animationDuration: ({animationSpeed}) => (`${animationSpeed}s`),
        animationFillMode: 'forwards',
    },
    '@keyframes fadeIn': {
        '0%': { opacity: 0 },
        '100%': { opacity: 1 },
    },
}));

export default function FadeInWords({ text, className, style, delay = 0.2, animationSpeed=1 }) {
    const classes = useStyles({ animationSpeed });
    const words = text.split(' ');

    return (
        <>
            {words.map((word, index) => {
                return (
                    <Typography className={[classes.textFadeIn, className]} style={{ ...style, animationDelay: `${index * delay}s` }}>
                        {(words.length === index + 1) ? word : word + '\u00a0'}
                    </Typography>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
}
```

**Desktop View:**
[image]

**Mobile View:**
[image]

Expected Mobile View:
[image]

Comment: Hi try to add `display: "inline-block"`, it will work for both desktop and mobile views! You can also check my ans... Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 import Styled from "styled-components";

 export default function FadeInWords({ text, className, style, delay = 0.2, animationSpeed=1 }) {
    const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
       const width = document.body.clientWidth;
       setSize(width);
    }, []);
    const classes = useStyles({ animationSpeed });
    const words = text.split(' ');

    return (
        <Wrapper width = {size}>
            {words.map((word, index) => {
                return (
                    <Typography className={[classes.textFadeIn, className]} style={{ ...style, animationDelay: `${index * delay}s` }}>
                        {(words.length === index + 1) ? word : word + '\u00a0'}
                    </Typography>
                );
            })}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = Styled.div`
    width: ${({ width }) => width};
`;
```

You are trying to give wrap to the word which doesn't work. Instead, give width to the whole sentence which will wrap the sentence to the next line according to the screen size.

I hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can try like this:

Only you have to add `display: "inline-block"` in `textFadeIn`

```
textFadeIn: {
    opacity: 0,
    display: "inline-block",
    animationName: "$fadeIn",
    animationDuration: ({ animationSpeed }) => `${animationSpeed}s`,
    animationFillMode: "forwards"
  },
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks. You're solution doesn't seem to change anything for me. I also took a look at your sandbox and it seems like your text is just one long word. Part of my challenge is handling sentences (i.e. with spaces) and if it is too long to show the entire sentence on one line - then to wrap around to the next line (without breaking any words - i.e. wrap in between words)

Comment: Hi I'll try to update my codsandbox soon!

Comment: I added an image of the expected behavior